# Election participation

Tags: discussion, election

Current election participation status is:

> Election closes in 3 days.
>
> 387 voters were eligible, 186 visited the site during the election, 115 visited the election page, and 60 voted

This is about 15% participation - Should we be worried or is this normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drupal Answers's election is pretty average, even on the high side for visits.

| Election | Visited % | Voted % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mathematics | Unavailable | 44% |
| CS Theory | 49% | 40% |
| GIS | 49% | 38% |
| WordPress | 42% | 31% |
| Physics | 41% | 27% |
| TeX - LaTex | 35% | 23% |
| SharePoint | 32% | 22% |
| Stats | 31% | 22% |
| Ask Ubuntu | 28% | 19% |
| Apple | 25% | 16% |
| Gaming | 22% | 16% |
| English | 23% | 15% |
| Database Admin. | 23% | 15% |
| Photography | 23% | 15% |
| Cooking | 20% | 15% |
| Electrical Eng. | 24% | 14% |
| Game Devel. | 23% | 13% |
| Unix & Linux | 21% | 13% |
| Bicycles | 21% | 13% |
| Programmers | 21% | 12% |
| IT Security | 19% | 12% |
| Stack Overflow | 32% | 11% |
| Pro Webmasters | 15% | 11% |
| DIY | 16% | 9% |
| Server Fault | 15% | 8% |
| Stack Overflow | 25% | 7% |
| Android | 11% | 7% |
| Super User | 11% | 5% |
| Mean | 27% | 17% |
| Median | 24% | 15% |
| Mode | 23% | 15% |